# Disable auto submit of datatable and add submit button

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a table that use [individual column filtering](http://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html) and i wanted to disable the auto submit feature when typing on a column filter. Is there a way to do this ?
The goal is to have a submit button that do this job.
Please note that i use also bstatesave and Colvis

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread: http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/320/add-search-button/p1

It outlines out to create a "Search" button instead of allowing the auto-submit.